# MongoDB find specific elements of an array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am looking to retrieve all _id in my subdocument that have no value for click

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59786f1238894a1344e1d61a"),
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T10:31:04.334Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59786f4df9f1c5cb764f9769"),
            "click" : "12"
        }, 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T12:46:12.397Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59788eebf9f1c5cb764f976f")
        }, 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T12:49:54.614Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59786fc0f9f1c5cb764f976a")
        }, 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T12:52:42.742Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5978909af9f1c5cb764f9770")
        }, 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-08-07T12:34:57.462Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59885e71e5ef9cdbf9c51fa2")
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59786f1238894a1344e1d61b"),
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T12:46:12.397Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59788eebf9f1c5cb764f976f")
        }, 
        {
            "dateAdd" : ISODate("2017-07-26T12:49:54.614Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59786fc0f9f1c5cb764f976a")
        }, 

    ]
}
```

I would like to recover these values:
59788eebf9f1c5cb764f976f,
59786fc0f9f1c5cb764f976a,
5978909af9f1c5cb764f9770,
59885e71e5ef9cdbf9c51fa2

With this request:

```
db.users.find({
    "products.click": {
        $exists: false 
    }
}, {
    "products._id": 1,
    "_id": 0
});
```

I have just have _id of the second documents.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use aggregation with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I make : users.aggregate(
      { $unwind: '$products.click' }
    ).exec()  I have no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find()` command will return all documents which match your condition but it will not allow you to filter the sub document array within those documents. In order to filter the sub document array you'll have to use an aggregation pipeline. Using a project+filter would be an option except that `$cond` does not support the `$exists` operator so instead you have to `$unwind` the products array so that you can filter it via a `$match` and then `$project` the results.

This example will return 4 'documents' each of which contains a `product._id`:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    // unwind the products array
    { $unwind: '$products' },
    // filter out any products which have a populated 'click' attribute 
    { $match: { 'products.click': { $exists: false } } },
    // only select the product id
    { $project: { _id: 0, 'products._id': 1 } }
])
```

Example response:

```
{
    "products" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59788eebf9f1c5cb764f976f")
    }
},
{
    "products" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59786fc0f9f1c5cb764f976a")
    }
},
{
    "products" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5978909af9f1c5cb764f9770")
    }
},
{
    "products" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59885e71e5ef9cdbf9c51fa2")
    }
}
```

If you want the selected product ids to be returned in one document like this ...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59786f1238894a1344e1d61a"),
    "productIds" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5978909af9f1c5cb764f9770")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59885e71e5ef9cdbf9c51fa2")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59786fc0f9f1c5cb764f976a")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59788eebf9f1c5cb764f976f")
        }
    ]
}
```

... then add a group step to the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('sample').aggregate([
    // unwind the products array
    { $unwind: '$products' },
    // filter out any products which have a populated 'click' attribute 
    { $match: { 'products.click': { $exists: false } } },
    // only select the product id
    { $project: { 'products._id': 1 } },
    // group the results by the parent document id merging the filtered product ids for each document into a new attribute: productIds
    { $group : { _id: '$_id', productIds: {$addToSet: '$products'} } }
])
```

Comment: Impressive, thank you very much for your help and your pedagogy.